# Why did Holly allow Butler to use Cam-foil if she knew it wouldn't fool security cameras?

Tags: artemis-fowl, artemis-fowl-the-eternity-code

*Artemis Fowl and the Eternity Code* has the following line of dialogue from Foaly:

> "Cameras have better eyes than humans. Did you ever see a TV picture on television? The camera breaks down the pixels. If you go down that corridor behind cam-foil, you're going to look like two people behind a projector screen."

If the above statement is correct, then why did Butler use Cam-foil while he was threatening Arno Blunt in the prison? It was also mentioned by Sid Commons that they might check the tapes.

**Why did Holly allow Butler to use Cam-foil if she knew that he would very well be visible when they checked the tapes?**

Comment: The camera in prison was definitely not as precise as the camera in Spiro's place

Comment: @Righter, what do you mean by precise here?

Comment: Eh, like good quality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Foaly had wiped Butler from the camera feed already**

Just before Butler puts on the camouflage foil, Holly twists a video clip around a cable on the wall and says:

> "OK," she said, listening to Foaly's voice in her ear. "We're in. **Foaly has wiped our patterns from the video. We are camera and mike-proof now.**"
>
> <sup>Chapter 11: The Invisible Man - *The Eternity Code*</sup>

The cam foil was used by Butler to scare Arno Blunt, and was already hacked off the camera feed.

Comment: nice observation! Looks like I've gotta read that book all over again. 